# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Flex Breaking with Brand Center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I currently have my brand logo centered, and two menus on the left and right of my brand. When heading down to the mobile size I'm trying to change my left-hand search menu item to be on the right but it's proving tricky, for some reason It's not actually flexing to the right and is wrapping to a new line.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
  </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/">
    <img src="logo.svg" height="25" class="d-inline-block align-top">
  </a>

  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="searchToggle">
               <i class="material-icons">search</i>
             </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end">
         <li class="nav-item search-mobile d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="searchToggle">
               <i class="material-icons">search</i>
             </a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Father's Day</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stores</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>


</nav>
```

I currently have two search menu's as it's changing location on the page, is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do when I run into that issue using Boostrap. I hope you find it just as useful. I First added a custom class of "move" to the parent UL element.

```
</ul>
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end move">
     <li class="nav-item search-mobile d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="searchToggle">
           <i class="material-icons" id="search">search</i>
         </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Father's Day</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Stores</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I then add the CSS by making the parent ul with the custom class of "move" to a position of relative. Then added the appropriate media query to adjust search to the top right.

```
ul .move {
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
#search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 12px;
 }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for